# Checking an ArrayList of Objects for a string

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble with looking through my ArrayList of FacebookPerson object for a string (name). This is my first project working with ArrayLists, and as such I have, at best, only a basic idea of what I'm doing. What I'm not understanding is why fbUsers.contains(name) does not seem to do anything, and how I can correctly search for a string name.

---testFacebook_ArrayList.java

```
package Facebook;

import java.util.*;

public class testFacebook_ArrayList {
    public static Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String name, mood;
        boolean exit = false;
        ArrayList<FacebookPerson> fbUsers = new ArrayList<FacebookPerson>();

        while(!exit){
        System.out.print("Enter the name of a facebook user to be created (enter #### to end creation & move to user selection): ");
        name = Input.next();
        Input.nextLine();

            if(name.equals("####")){
            exit = true;
            }
            else if(fbUsers.contains(new FacebookPerson(name))){
                System.out.println("Error, name already exists. Try again.");
                continue;
            }
            else{
                fbUsers.add(new FacebookPerson(name));
            }
        }
        exit = false;
        while (!exit){
            System.out.print("Enter a user's name to modify their mood (#### to terminate the program): ");
            name = Input.nextLine();

            if (name.equals("####")){
                System.out.println("Program terminated.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            else if (fbUsers.contains(new FacebookPerson(name))){
                System.out.print("Enter a mood for " + name + ": ");
                mood = Input.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < fbUsers.size(); i++){
                    if(fbUsers.get(i).equals(new FacebookPerson(name))){
                        fbUsers.get(i).setMood(mood);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Unrecognized name. Try again.");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---FacebookPerson.java

```
  // This is the FacebookPerson_Graphics class
  // Written by Dr. Xiaolin Hu
  // 03/05/2015
  package Facebook;

  public class FacebookPerson{

  private String myName;
  protected String myMood;
  protected Facebook myfacebook;

  public FacebookPerson(String name){
      myName = name;
      myfacebook = new Facebook(myName);
      //System.out.println("FacebookPerson's constructor");
  }

  public FacebookPerson(){

  }

  public String getName(){
      return myName;
  }

  public void setMood(String newMood){
     myMood = newMood;
     myfacebook.setContent(myMood);
  }

  public String getMood(){
      return myMood;
  }

}
```

---Facebook.java

```
// This is the Facebook class
// Wrriten by Dr. Xiaolin Hu
// 03/05/2015
package Facebook;

import java.awt.*;

public class Facebook{

   private String name;
   private String content;
   DrawingPanel panel;
   private Graphics g;

   public Facebook(String nm){
       content = "undefined";
       name = nm;

       // Create the drawing panel
       panel = new DrawingPanel(200, 150);
       g = panel.getGraphics();

       // display name
       g.drawString(name+"'s mood is undefined.", 20, 75);
   }

   public void setContent(String newContent){
    content = newContent;
        if(content.equals("happy")){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 150);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            // display mood
            g.drawString(name+"'s mood is:"+ "happy", 20, 75);
        }
        else{
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 150);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString(name+"'s mood is:"+ content, 20, 75);
        }
   }

   public String getContent(){
    return content;
   }
}
```

Comment: add code for `FacebookPerson`

Comment: change it to  `fbUsers.contains(new FacebookPerson(name))`

Comment: I'm assuming because you are doing `fbUsers.contains(name)` as `name` is a `String` but `fbUsers` contains `FacebookPerson` you most likely would need to make your own method for this. Or do what @Fungucide said above

Comment: Unfortunately Fungucide's method did not work. It seems to ignore it completely still.

Comment: @Calderious are you sure..

Comment: Can you just post the complete code that you have?

Comment: Most likely somthing weird with the input. your input reader does not just have the text I think that it also contains the new line.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know why... The name you are searching for is within FacebookPerson's constructor which .contains cannot search. You should make another string array list to handle name overlaps

Comment: This is great, thank you. I will implement it immediately and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a for loop for every user and call getName();

```
for (FacebookPerson fbp : fbUsers ){
     if (fbp.getName().equals(name)){
          System.out.println("Error, name already exists. Try again.");
          continue;
     }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this still does not work for me. Even with this comparison, it still seems to be ignored.

Comment: Please just post the whole code so I can help you debug

Comment: Done. Though, you should know that there are some other issues with my code as well not relating to this quesiton.

Comment: @Fungucide you do not compare `String` like that.

Comment: @Fungucide please see the `if` condition in your alternative solution

Comment: I'll fix that I'm kinda sleepy

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 2d array list to store the information and link it to the name. That would fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Calderious,

You need to override and implement FacebookPerson's `equals(...)` method in order for contains to work. If you look at the List's `contains(...)` javadoc, it specifically mentions:

> ... returns `true` if and only if this collection contains at least one
>   element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

add the following in your class

```
public class FacebookPerson {
  ...

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // your equals logic goes here
  }

  ...
}
```

or even better, IDEs can now create this based on your declared attributes. In Eclipse, you just need to right click on the code > `Source` > `Generate hashCode() and equals()`.

I hope that helps.